# Why doesn't master theorem solve $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n\lg\lg n$?

Tags: asymptotics, master-theorem

Given two recurrences:

1. $T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + n \lg \lg n$
2. $T(n) = 4 T(n/2) + n \lg \lg n$

I'd think that both works for master theorem, but the solution is that the first one cannot use masters theorem while the second one works with masters theorem. The only difference here is the $a$ value (2 vs 4).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the statement of the master theorem on Wikipedia. Consider a recurrence
$$ T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n). $$

1. If $f(n) = O(n^c)$ for $c < \log_b a$ then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$.
2. If $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a} \log^k n)$ for $k \geq 0$ then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a} \log^{k+1} n)$. (Extensions handle all $k$.)
3. If $f(n) = \Omega(n^c)$ for $c > \log_b a$ and $f$ is "reasonable" then $T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$.

In your case, the function $f$ satisfies neither of the three cases, and so the master theorem does not apply. It almost satisfies the second case, but instead of $f(n)$ scaling like $n^{\log_b a} \log^k n$ for some constant $k$, it scales like $n^{\log_b a} \log\log n$.

We can use the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) instead to conclude that $T(n) = \Theta(n\log n\log\log n)$.